# What amazon ec2 would be suggested for an ecommerce website with windows and sql server?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-ec2, hosting

We are running an eCommerce venture that has around 2000 unique visitors in a day. The total data is around 6 GB as of now.

We are using SQL Server as our database and in the coming months the website may scale up to 10000 users per day.

From this [link](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/05/choosing-the-right-ec2-instance-type-for-your-application.html) deciphered that it would be best to use M1 instance but could anyone help really clueless as to what to purchase from these options.

**Note:** Our budget is around 170 Dollars PM.

**EDIT:** The number of concurrent users we have had is around 150

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to fit everything in memory.  If you can't due to budget, you need to make sure the disk response times are up to par for your expected load.  You application can vary widely.  One visit to a homepage could generate many queries, or maybe you have application caching set up - so it's hard for anyone to just tell you.  You should also get solid numbers on your peak number of concurrent users so you can plan for that.  You don't mention your current environment, but you can get some numbers about CPU, Disk MB Read/Writes/s and memory used to help you get the right size.

I'd look at the xlarge m1.  That gives you 15GB of memory to play with.  You'll be able to cache all the data you need and have some left over for the OS and also have some room to grow.  CPU probably won't be your issue, but be sure to check out your current use.

If you have some time to spend on it, I'd try setting up JMeter to do some load testing and see how many concurrent users you can max out with one of the cheaper options.

This topic may be better suited to ServerFault.

Comment: I used m1 large before the costs are massive with like 700 or so dollars with sql server web

Comment: I see.  Like I said, the best thing to do is to set it up on a cheaper option and verify the performance.  If you can't get the whole db in memory, you'll want to make sure the IO to persistent storage is adequate for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to check at the reserved instances in heavy category where you can get interesting discounts if you plan to run it for a year or similar.

But with that budget you should be thinking about an m1.medium instance, which might be a little tight for your requirements.